# Completness and finite dimensions

Tags: functional-analysis, complete-spaces

I am currently studying Section 2.4 Finite dimensional normed spaces in Kreyszig - Introduction to Functional Analysis.

In particular,
**Theorem 2.4-2 (Completeness):** Every finite dimensional subspace $Y$ of a normed space $X$ is complete. In particular, every finite dimensional normed space is complete.

The proof of this theorem is clear to me, but I had an example in mind which seems to contradict the statement of the theorem.

If we consider $X = C[0,1]$ with the norm $||x|| = \sup_{t \in[0,1]} |x(t)|$ and define $$Y:=\{p:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:p(t) := \sum_{j=0}^n c_j t^j, n \leq N\}$$ for some fixed $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then $Y$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $X$ since $\{1,t,t^2,\ldots,t^N\}$ is a basis. However, the Cauchy sequence $(p_n)$ defined by $p_n(t) = \sum_{j=0}^n t^j/j!$ converges to the exponential function, which is not a polynomial, so not every Cauchy sequence converges, we conclude that $Y$ is not complete.

Where is my example false?

Comment: $p_n$ for $n> N$ is not in your space $Y$.

Comment: Nice!! Didn't see that. Thanks.

Comment: But this does show that the subspace of polynomials (which is infinite dimensional) is not a normed space under this norm.

Comment: For example, $Z:= \text{span}\{1,t,t^2,t^3,\ldots\}$. This argument would show $Z$ is not *complete*, but I think it would still be a normed space.

Comment: Ahh yes. Correct!